# How can I import lodash with svelte?

Tags: lodash, svelte, rollupjs

I simply wanted to import lodash `import _ from 'lodash';`, and I keep having the following error:

```
rollup v2.23.0
bundles src/main.js → public\build\bundle.js...
[!] (plugin commonjs) SyntaxError: Unexpected token (434:48) in C:\my-svelte\node_modules\lodash\lodash.js
node_modules\lodash\lodash.js (434:48)
432:
433:   /** Detect free variable `process` from Node.js. */
434:   var freeProcess = moduleExports && freeGlobal.process;
                                                     ^
435:
436:   /** Used to access faster Node.js helpers. */
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (434:48) in C:\my-svelte\node_modules\lodash\lodash.js
    at Object.pp$4.raise (C:\my-svelte\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\rollup.js:15135:13)
    at Object.pp.unexpected (C:\my-svelte\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\rollup.js:12906:8)
    at Object.pp$3.parseIdent (C:\my-svelte\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\rollup.js:15086:10)
    at Object.parseIdent (C:\my-svelte\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\rollup.js:18737:27)
    at Object.parseIdent (C:\my-svelte\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\rollup.js:18969:27)
    at Object.pp$3.parseSubscript (C:\my-svelte\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\rollup.js:14380:62)
    at Object.parseSubscript (C:\my-svelte\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\rollup.js:18640:37)
    at Object.pp$3.parseSubscripts (C:\my-svelte\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\rollup.js:14355:24)
    at Object.pp$3.parseExprSubscripts (C:\my-svelte\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\rollup.js:14340:21)
    at Object.pp$3.parseMaybeUnary (C:\my-svelte\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\rollup.js:14314:17)
```

I used `npx degit sveltejs/template my-svelte` to create the app.

I tried `lodash-es` as well, same thing: `[!] (plugin commonjs) SyntaxError: Unexpected token (13:46) in C:\my-svelte\node_modules\lodash-es_nodeUtil.js`.

This is definitely a lodash related issue, specifically related to that line 434. Everything else I tried to import works just fine:

```
import {v4} from 'uuid';
import {Subject} from "rxjs";
import ReconnectingWebSocket from 'reconnecting-websocket';
...
```

EDIT: The problem is caused by `import replace from '@rollup/plugin-replace';` in `rollup.config.js` :(

Now I need to figure out how to get .env variables into Svelte without `@rollup/plugin-replace`...

Comment: Maybe format of lodash are you using? You probably want the [es version](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash-es)

Comment: Tried es too, same thing [!] (plugin commonjs) SyntaxError: Unexpected token (13:46) in C:\my-svelte\node_modules\lodash-es\_nodeUtil.js

Answer (score 6):

I use `lodash-es` and works fine. I even get nice tree-shaking with that.

```
<script>
    import { upperCase } from 'lodash-es';
    export let name;
</script>

<p>{upperCase(name)}</p>
```

Answer (score -1):

**Edit**

The answer was pretty old and code improves: my application now uses this to import lodash on a svelte file for quite a while - I hope it works for the OP also now:

```js
import _ from "lodash";
```

**Old Post**
(a commenter mentioned that this does not work anymore, for whatever reasons - I leave it just here)

This works for me in my svelte files:

```
<script>
  const _ = require('lodash');

  //...
</script>
```

I often get into trouble with `import` on my electron/svelte project but `require` usually helps.

Comment: Well, this doesn't work anymore.

Comment: @Alper - some more info is always helpful ;) I checked my code and actually changed to `import _ from 'lodash'` and *that* (still) works well.